# Twitter bootstrap-formtastic failing rspec test after adding dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I have a bootstrap formtastic form which was passing all of my rspec tests.

Until I change one of the fields from a normal text_field to a drop-down list

```
<%= f.input :gender, :label => "Gender" %>
```

to

```
<%= f.input :gender, 
:label => "Gender",
:collection => [["Female", "F"], ["Male", "M"]] 
%>
```

then I get the following error message:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in "Gender", with: "F"
Capybara::ElementNotFound: cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Gender' found.
```

RSpec seem to be complaining the following line:

```
before do
    fill_in "Gender", with: "F"
    ...
```

Did I do something wrong? Coding, Configuration, Everything? Can someone please help?

Comment: Just a guess: try `fill_in "gender", with :"F"`. Or does `fill_in` use the label to find the field to fill in?

Comment: I've tried but no luck, same result.

Comment: Mhh seems like `fill_in` works just for text fields, text areas or password fields. But you have a select menu - so you need another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As klump says you should use the proper method to select the value.

Since you are using Capybara that is `select "F", :from => "Gender"`

You can find more info in the [Capybara API](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master#Interacting_with_forms)